# KnockoutJS Mapping Plugin not working on a Linux box

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I have a KnockoutJS mapping that works great on OS X. However, the same code fails on a production Linux box with

`"Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function"` error in `knockout.mapping.js?body=1:467`

```
    var mapping = {
        key: function(data) {
            return data.id;        
        },
        deployments: {
            create: function (options) {

                // THIS PART OF CODE IS NOT WORKING
                var deploymentsMapping = { 'observe': ["current_tag", "current_serial", "component.available_tags"], 'ignore': ["created_at", "updated_at"] }
                var innerModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(options.data, deploymentsMapping);
                // END OF NON WORKING CODE

                innerModel.current_tag.dirtyFlag = new ko.dirtyFlag(innerModel.current_tag);
                innerModel.current_serial.dirtyFlag = new ko.dirtyFlag(innerModel.current_serial);

                innerModel.deployed_tag = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(innerModel.current_tag());
                innerModel.deployed_serial = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(innerModel.current_serial());

                return innerModel;
            },
        },
    }

    var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(jsondata, mapping);
```

If i remove `deploymentsMapping` from `ko.mapping.fromJS()` it works fine.

Any idea what could be wrong? This same code works great on my laptop with OS X on it.

Using 'Knockout Mapping plugin v2.4.1' with KnockoutJS 3.0'